# Microsoft Graph API getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail end point returns S2SUnauthorized Invalid permission

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

When i set the `Reports.Read.All` permission in microsoft graph explorer it gives the data.

code written in graph.service.ts

```
async getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(): Promise<any[]> {
  try {
    // https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='D7')?$format=application/json
    let result = await this.graphClient
      .api("/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='D7')")
      .version('beta')
      .get();
    console.log(result);
    return result.value;
  }
  catch (error) {
    this.alertsService.add('Could not get getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail', JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
  }
}
```

When i call the above method in angular app it gives the following error.

> Could not get getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail

Error message:

```
{
  "statusCode": 403,
  "code": "S2SUnauthorized",
  "message": "Invalid permission.",
  "requestId": "5ca8c5f6-59d0-476b-97b3-ca165ecd679f",
  "date": "2020-06-29T06:20:23.000Z",
  "body": "{\"code\":\"S2SUnauthorized\",\"message\":\"Invalid permission.\",\"innerError\":{\"date\":\"2020-06-29T11:50:23\",\"request-id\":\"5ca8c5f6-59d0-476b-97b3-ca165ecd679f\"}}"
}
```

Comment: How are you authenticating?

Comment: I followed this url to create this project. [Microsoft Graph Quick Start](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start?platform=option-angular)
By default It uses Implicit grant flow.

Comment: Are you still looking for help here?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and it was because we had been assigned Delegated permissions. Changing to Application permissions resolved the issue for me.

[azure application api permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToQtk.png)